# Trying to understand MassTransit Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to understand exactly what the MassTransit Prometheus metrics are showing, since I'm seeing some weird numbers.

For example, the metric called `mt_published_total` should be showing the amount of published messages for a certain type, but the scale of the numbers seem way off to me.

In the image below, the top part is the metric "Outgoing Messages" for the Service Bus in Azure (filtered on the message type). The bottom part of the image is `mt_published_total` for the same message type (`sum(rate(mt_publish_total{message_type="IItemInsertedEvent"}[1m])) by (message_type)`)

So it looks like the scale if off by about 1000x, and I don't know why. Is my prometheus query off? Am I comparing apples and oranges?

Using MassTransit 7.3.1.

[image]

Comment: This [video](https://youtu.be/OhYGYaPPBec) might help?